# Добавить имя пользователя в отправленном email

Tags: python, django, email

Использую встроенную функцию для оправки почты. Заголовок и содержание приходят. Как добавить в текст от кого пришло?
Имя пользователя с запроса вытаскиваю, а дальше как?

```py
def send_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user # Добавить отправителя в почту
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                mail = send_mail(form.cleaned_data['subject'], form.cleaned_data['content'],
                          '3250874@ukr.net', ['degtyarevvladimirr@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
                if mail:
                    messages.success(request, 'Письмо отправлено')
                    return redirect('about')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Ошибка при отправке')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Ошибка при заполнении')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "private_site/email.html", {'form': form, 'title': "Обратная связь"})
```

Comment: @Nyuhnyash, подскажите, пожалуйста, на примере как следует верно писать

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)
параметр `from_email` (3-й по счёту в функции `django.core.mail.send_mail`) может принимать значения в формате:

```
"Fred" <fred@example.com>
```

Comment: Третий параметр не меняется. Это то, что нужно для smtp. Вопрос решил так:
'''
                    email_from = f'От: {username}'
                    body = {
                        'subject': form.cleaned_data['subject'],
                        'content': form.cleaned_data['content'],
                    }
                    message = "\n".join(body.values())
                    mail = send_mail(email_from, message, '3250874@ukr.net', ['degtyarevvladimirr@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
'''

Comment: @VladimirDegtyarev в плане не меняется? В вашем решении вы просто добавили имя пользователя в тему сообщения, вообще-то для этого существует поле `From` и почтовые клиенты умеют с ним корректно работать.